# Celery tasks same schedule with offset

Tags: python, django, celery, cron, schedule

I have several tasks, something like this:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task1': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.task1',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10),
    },
    'task2': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.task2',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
    },
    'task3': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.task3',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=15),
    },
    ...
}
```

So, task1 will be run in *:*:10, *:*:20, *:*:30, *:*:40, *:*:50 and *:*:00

task2 will be run in *:*:30 and *:*:00

task3 will be run in *:*:15, *:*:30, *:*:45 and *:*:00

Then the tasks concurs always in *:*:30 and *:*:00. Is there any way to add an offset. I want to get something like this:

task1 (offset=2) run in *:*:12, *:*:22, *:*:32, *:*:42, *:*:52 and *:*:02

task2 (offset=7) run in *:*:37 and *:*:07

task3 (offset=0) run in *:*:15, *:*:30, *:*:45 and *:*:00

I have read the documentation, and I think I must use crontab, but is not there another way more nice? And crontab has not for seconds configuration :-(

Comment: I implemented once [schedulesince](https://gist.github.com/glowka/a3936877cb754d30e3ff753e1b94d67b) (`timedelta(seconds=10)` is normally converted to `schedule(timedelta(seconds=10))`). This is not exactly what you asked for, but maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks @glowka I can use it like example... but yes it does not solve my problem :-(

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Goin: That seems to be very unusual requirement. Perhaps there's an easier way to structure the underlying architecture/requirements?

Comment: @sdolan It is not a solution :-P It is very basic. Now I have every minute several times with a lot of run tasks and other several times without executing anything. I want to distribute the tasks, but I don't want to change the interval, only the initial point

Answer (score 3):

According to [celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#available-fields):

> You can also define your own custom schedule types, by extending the
>   interface of [schedule](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.schedules.html#celery.schedules.schedule).

So here is my solution:

```
from datetime import timedelta

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import schedule


class MySchedule(schedule):
    def __init__(self, run_every=None, offset=None):
        self._run_every = run_every
        self._offset = offset if offset is not None else timedelta(seconds=0)
        self._do_offset = True if self._offset else False
        super(MySchedule, self).__init__(
            run_every=self._run_every + self._offset)

    def is_due(self, last_run_at):
        ret = super(MySchedule, self).is_due(last_run_at)
        if self._do_offset and ret.is_due:
            self._do_offset = False
            **self._offset = datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)** #bug fix
            self.run_every = self._run_every
            ret = super(MySchedule, self).is_due(last_run_at)
        return ret

    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (self._run_every, self._offset)


app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'task1': {
        'task': 'tasks.task1',
        'schedule': MySchedule(
            run_every=timedelta(seconds=10), offset=timedelta(seconds=2)),
    },
    'task2': {
        'task': 'tasks.task2',
        'schedule': MySchedule(
            run_every=timedelta(seconds=30), offset=timedelta(seconds=7)),
    },
    'task3': {
        'task': 'tasks.task3',
        'schedule': MySchedule(
            run_every=timedelta(seconds=15), offset=timedelta(seconds=0)),
    },
}


@app.task
def task1():
    print('task1')


@app.task
def task2():
    print('task2')


@app.task
def task3():
    print('task3')
```

You can write your own `MySchedule` and extend it from `BaseSchedule` to have more control.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by using below steps:

1.You don't need to add `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` on the `settings.py` file

2.In `__init__.py` file in `api` app add below code:

```
import tasks
```

3.And then on the `tasks.py` file:

```
from datetime import datetime

from celery import Celery


app = Celery()
run_id = None

@app.task
def task1():
    print('every 10 seconds:', datetime.now().second)

@app.task
def task2():
    print('every 30 seconds:', datetime.now().second)

@app.task
def task3():
    print('every 15 seconds:', datetime.now().second)

@app.task
def run(sender):
    global app, run_id
    # Schedule other tasks
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, task1.s())
    sender.add_periodic_task(30.0, task2.s())
    sender.add_periodic_task(15.0, task3.s())
    # Stop self running later times
    app.control.revoke(run_id)

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    global run_id
    now = datetime.now()
    run_id = sender.add_periodic_task((30 if now.second < 30 else 60) - now.second, run.s(sender))
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirty due monkey patching, but works. The main problem is that *django-celery-beat* is creating schedule instances from its schedule types based on DB entries, so you have no chance to register custom schedule with custom `nowfun` https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/blob/5a72e0a1911a7fef1fb725c91d10a61ca1e0e83f/django_celery_beat/models.py#L326-L334

```
import environ

from datetime import timedelta

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import BaseSchedule


env = environ.Env()

CELERY_OFFSET_MINUTES = env("CELERY_OFFSET_MINUTES", default=0)


def offset_now(self):
    if self.nowfun:
        # TzAwareCrontab does not use `self.app.now`
        now = self.nowfun() + timedelta(minutes=CELERY_OFFSET_MINUTES)
    else:
        now = self.app.now()
    return now


BaseSchedule.now = offset_now


class OffsetCelery(Celery):
    def now(self):
        return super().now() + timedelta(minutes=CELERY_OFFSET_MINUTES)


app = OffsetCelery(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to solve this problem with a solution a little different like vasi1y solution. But this solution and the previous solutions do not work...

```
class schedule_offset(schedule):

    def __init__(self, run_every=None, offset=None,
                relative=False, nowfun=None, app=None):
        self._run_every = run_every
        if offset is None:
            offset = 0
        self._offset = maybe_timedelta(offset)
        self._executing = 0
        super(schedule_offset, self).__init__(
            run_every=self._run_every, relative=relative, nowfun=nowfun, app=app)

    def is_due(self, last_run_at):
        last_run_at = last_run_at + self._offset
        last_run_at = self.maybe_make_aware(last_run_at)
        rem_delta = self.remaining_estimate(last_run_at)
        remaining_s = timedelta_seconds(rem_delta)
        if remaining_s == 0:
            ret = schedstate(is_due=True, next=self.seconds + self._offset.seconds)
            if self._executing < 2:
                self._executing += 1
                if self._executing == 2:
                    self._offset = maybe_timedelta(0)
            return ret
        return schedstate(is_due=False, next=remaining_s)

    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (self._run_every, self._offset, self.relative, self.nowfun)


CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task1': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.task1',
        'schedule': schedule_offset(timedelta(seconds=10), offset=2),
    },
    'task2': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.task2',
        'schedule': schedule_offset(timedelta(seconds=30), offset=7),
    },
    'task3': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.task3',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=15),
    },
    ...
}
```